# sed to split verilog bus into individual port

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to convert a particular `Verilog Bus` into individual split form using `sed` or `awk` command.

### Input

```
module test ( temp_bus[3:0], temp_B[1:0] )
    input [3:0] temp_bus;
    output [1:0] temp_B;
endmodule
```

### Output

```
module test ( temp_bus[3], temp_bus[2], temp_bus[1], temp_bus[0], temp_B[1], temp_B[0])
   input temp_bus[3], temp_bus[2], temp_bus[1], temp_bus[0];
   output temp_B[1], temp_B[0];
endmodule
```

### Edit1: Case with multiple declaration

```
module test ( temp_bus[3:0], temp_B[1:0] , temp_C[1:0] )
    input [3:0] temp_bus;
    output [1:0] temp_B , temp_c;
endmodule
```

Resultant must have 
`output temp_B[1], temp_B[0], temp_C[1], temp_C[0] ;`

[cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) has almost done given the best solution.

Comment: this would be very difficult to do with sed.  try awk or perl or python instead.

Comment: Answerers are so focussed on the tools that they've probably not noticed that this won't work in standard Verilog 2005.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP - i've never even used verilog. i was focused on the input and the output.

Comment: @JigarGhandi Your **Edit1** belongs in a new question, it's not just a minor variation of the original question.  It requires a different approach, actually parsing the lines and remembering what has been seen before rather than making relatively simple, stateless transformations of whatever the current line is.

Comment: @cas I agree , Well I just edited the question. I am working on your answer to go for further modification.
Meanwhile I feel the  **Edit1** should be stated for reader's use.

Comment: new version handles both inputs.  algorithm had to be re-written, to have nested while loops and an array to remember the `[n:n]` expansion for the `input` and `output` lines, but it didn't require overly-complicated parsing like I thought it might.  the basic idea remains the same, for each input line, split it into whitespace-delimited fields, do any special processing each field might need, then rejoin the post-processed fields into one line and print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in `perl`:

(revised version will handle both of your sample inputs.  It also looks like a semi-colon inside `[]` doesn't confuse the markdown syntax highlighting)

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

sub expand {
  my ($name,$start,$stop) = @_;
  my $step = ( $start < $stop ? 1 : -1);
  my @names=();

  my $i = $start;
  while ($i ne $stop + $step) {
    push @names, "$name\[$i\]";
    $i += $step;
  }
  return @names;
};

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  s/([(),;])/ $1/g;   # add a space before any commas, semi-colons, and
                      #  parentheses, so they get split into separate fields.

  my @l=();           # array to hold the output line as it's being built

  my @line = split ;  # split input line into fields, with 1-or-more
                      # whitespace characters (spaces or tabs) between each
                      # field.

  my $f=0;            # field counter

  while ($f < @line) {
    if ( $line[$f] =~ m/module/io ) {
        push @l,$line[$f++];
        while ($f < @line) {
            if ( $line[$f] =~ m/^(.*)\[(\d+):(\d+)\]$/o ) {
                # expand [n:n] on module line
                push @l, join(", ",expand($1,$2,$3));
            } else { 
                push @l, $line[$f]
            };
            $f++;
        };
    } elsif ($line[$f] =~ m/^(?:input|output)$/io) {
        # use sprintf() to indent first field to 10 chars wide.
        $line[$f] = sprintf("%10s",$line[$f]);
        push @l, $line[$f++];;

        my @exp = ();
        while ($f < @line) {
            if ( $line[$f] =~ m/^\[(\d+):(\d+)\]$/o ) {
                # extract and store [n:n] on input or output lines
                @exp=($1,$2);
            } elsif ( $line[$f] =~ m/^\w+$/io) {
                # expand "word" with [n:n] on input or output lines
                push @l,join(", ",expand($line[$f],@exp));
            } else {
                push @l, $line[$f];
            };
            $f++;
        };

    } else {
      # just append everything else to the output @l array
      push @l, $line[$f];
    };
    $f++;
  }
  print join(" ",@l),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./jigar.pl ./jigar.txt 
module test ( temp_bus[3], temp_bus[2], temp_bus[1], temp_bus[0] , temp_B[1], temp_B[0] ) 
     input temp_bus[3], temp_bus[2], temp_bus[1], temp_bus[0] ; 
    output temp_B[1], temp_B[0] ; 
endmodule
```

Output from your second sample:

```
$ ./jigar2.pl jigar2.txt 
module test ( temp_bus[3], temp_bus[2], temp_bus[1], temp_bus[0] , temp_B[1], temp_B[0] , temp_C[1], temp_C[0] )
     input temp_bus[3], temp_bus[2], temp_bus[1], temp_bus[0] ;
    output temp_B[1], temp_B[0] , temp_c[1], temp_c[0] ;
endmodule
```

Comment: This code works fine, But I need to modify it for certain cases . I am updating the question containing such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you are only interested in the intervals in your example, it would be awkward, but not too difficult, to do in `sed`:

```
/(in|out)put/s/(\[.*\]+) *(.*);/\2\1;/
s/([A-Za-z_]+)\[3:0\]/\1[3], \1[2:0]/g
s/([A-Za-z_]+)\[2:0\]/\1[2], \1[1:0]/g
s/([A-Za-z_]+)\[1:0\]/\1[1], \1[0]/g
```

A slightly more general solution is also somewhat more involved:

```
/(in|out)put/s/(\[.*\]+) *(.*);/\2\1;/
/\[[0-9:]+\]/s/$/#9876543210/
:a {
   s/([A-Za-z_]+)\[([0-9]):0\](.*)(#[0-9]+)\2([0-9]+)$/\1[\2], \1[\5]\3\4\2\5/
   ta
}
s/#9876543210$//
:b {
   s/([A-Za-z_]+)\[([0-9])([0-9]+)\]/\1[\2], \1[\3]/
   tb
}
```

Not that I recommend doing it that way.

Comment: IMO, awkward is difficult.

Comment: should I go for `Tcl` or `Perl` ?

Comment: I'd use `perl` but use whichever language you're most comfortable with.

Comment: BTW, in case performance is important here (which it shouldn't be unless you're processing millions of lines).  The `sed` version here ran in 0.005 seconds with your 4-line input.  My `perl` version ran in 0.009 seconds (perl has greater startup overhead than sed).   Copying your 4 lines 500 times into a second file (total 2000 lines, 51KB), the `sed` script took between 0.044 seconds and 0.053 seconds to run.  My `perl` script rain in 0.028 to 0.033 seconds.  With 1M lines (25MB), sed took 20.1-20.9 seconds, while perl took 9.4-9.6 seconds.  `Tcl` would be a lot slower than either sed or perl

Comment: @cas I'm not surprised. The `sed` version is inherently inefficient, as the iteration has to be implemented via regular expression matching.

Comment: I was surprised.  I was expecting the sed version to be quite a bit faster when i started timing them.  regexps aren't exactly fast, but I thought the overhead of multiple function calls (join and expand) per line/field and working with multiple arrays in perl would more than offset the complicated regexps in sed.